# C: More than 2 successors of statement without switch in code

Tags: c

I'm writing a program for C-Code-analysis.

Considering there can't be switch-statements in the code I want to analyze, is there a way a statement has more than 2 successor-statements?

As far as I know, `if`, `while` and some others have exactly 2 successor-statements, and the rest that I can think of have one, and I can't think of another case, where there are more than two.

With my question, I mean the successors within the same function, not considering a function-call with the called function (or it's first statement) as target.

Is there a case I didn't notice?

**EDIT:**

As an example, i want to analyze the following code (I know it can be optimized, just an example):

```
int func(int z){
    int y;
    if (z<0){
        y=1;
    }
    else{
        y=2;
    }
    return y;
}
```

I get the following structure (described by the comments, not so easy to describe in textual way):

```
int y;         //first statement, not successor of another statement
if (z<0)       //successor of `int y`, has two successors
y=1;           //first successor of `if (z<0)`
y=2;           //second successor of `if (z<0)`
return y;      //successor of `y=1` and `y=2`
```

So the statement `if (z<0)` has 2 successors, one for the then-branch and one for the else branch. So my question is, if there are constructs like if, but with more than 2 successors. A loop would also have 2 successors, the loop body and the statement after the loop.

I hope my question is now more clear.

Comment: What is your exact definition of a *successor statement*?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. You can use if (condition1){...} else if(condition2){...} else if (condition3){...} [...] as many times as you want, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: @DamienBaldy , then the `else if` is, in my case, the second successor of the `if`, the next `else if`, the seconds successor of the first one, and the `else` the second successor of the last `else if`

Comment: I don't get it. Can you give an example of your problem with code in your original post?

Comment: *"A loop would also have 2 successors, the loop body and the statement after the loop."* This is not consistent with your description; with that reasoning, `if else` should have third successor, after the the then and else branches.

Comment: Also, do you count conditional function `return` from `while` loop as one extra successor?

Comment: No, because the statement after the else is the successor of the last statement in the `if` and the last statement of the `else` block. If there is no else-block, it is the successor of the last statement in the `then`-block, and the second successor of the `if`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is within your scope, but consider [function pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_pointer) - you simply don't know where you will end up:

```
void foo(void (*bar)()) {
  bar();
}
```

Also, there are [`setjmp()` and `longjmp()`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setjmp.h) that might make things complicated.

Concerning your statement that

> if and while have exactly 2 successor-statements, and all others have
>   one

These are not the only ones. Think about `for` loops.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I forgot about the other constructs (like for), thanks for pointing this out :)
Since the analysis is function-wise, a function-call has only one successor, the statement afterwards.
So the question is more within the scope of one funciton, I will edit my question.